# Cross product without reordering (noncommutative)

Tags: physics, products, order

**Not related to question**

I assume this question (as it is of very general structure) might have been asked before, unfortunately I did not find an answer to it - despite what I used as search queries. If it already has been answered a reference is greatly appreciated.

---

**Question**

Assume a cross product is calculated as in

```
Cross[{d, e, f}, {a, b, c}]
(* Out: {c e - b f, -c d + a f, b d - a e} *).
```

Then MMA uses the commutative properties, i.e. $ec = c e$, to simplify the result. Though, my variables are not commutative implying that $ec \neq ce$ holds. I already know about `NonCommutativeMultiply` but do not see a possibility to include it here. How is it possible to ensure that the exact order is preserved for (repeated) applications of Cross to vectors/`List` objects?

---

**Sense of this question**

For all of you who are astonished why the heck anybody wants to preserve the order in cross multiplication: The variables are physical operators in reality such that $AB = BA + [A,B]$ where $[.,.]$ means the commutator. Thus, *not changing* the multiplication order ensures my results are also valid for noncommuting operators $A,B$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's handy to use a wrapper for things like vectors with nonstandard properties. So, choose a name like `ncVec` for your non-commutative vectors. Define its behavior in an upvalue:

```
Cross[ncVec[x_, y_, z_], ncVec[u_, v_, w_]] ^:= 
 ncVec[y ** w - z ** v, -x ** w + z ** u, x ** v - y ** u]

Cross[ncVec[d, e, f], ncVec[a, b, c]]
(* ncVec[e ** c - f ** b, -d ** c + f ** a, d ** b - e ** a] *)
```

And, of course, you may then define more special behaviors with additional upvalues.

Comment: Elegant and simple. Exactly what I was looking for.